# Error in Converting Raster to Polygon using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

my script  converts selected raster file to polygon, then from polygon it dissolves and export as dxf:

This is my script :

```
from qgis.core import QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas

import processing

import os.path

from datetime import datetime, timedelta


raster_layer = iface.activeLayer()



# Polygonize raster layer

polygonize = processing.runAndLoadResults(

    "gdal:polygonize",

    {

        'INPUT': raster_layer,

        'BAND': 1,

        'FIELD': 'DN',

        'EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS': False,

        'EXTRA': '',

        'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'

    }

)



# Dissolve polygons

dissolve = processing.runAndLoadResults(

    "native:dissolve",

    {

        'INPUT': polygonize['OUTPUT'],

        'FIELD': [],

        'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'

    }

)



# Define output path

path_file = 'C:/Users/CMCA/Downloads'



# Generate file name

out_name = raster_layer.name()[-8:]

archive = f'{path_file}/{out_name}_HEIC_3rdFill.dxf'



# Export dissolved layer as DXF

processing.runAndLoadResults(

    "native:dxfexport",

    {

        'LAYERS': [

            {

                'layer': dissolve['OUTPUT'],

                'attributeIndex': -1

            }

        ],

        'SYMBOLOGY_MODE': 1,

        'SYMBOLOGY_SCALE': 1e+06,

        'ENCODING': 'cp1250',

        'CRS': QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('Project CRS: USER: 100000'),

        'USE_LAYER_TITLE': False,

        'FORCE_2D': False,

        'MTEXT': True,

        'OUTPUT': archive

    }

)



print('Done')
```

this is the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.2\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
exec(code, self.locals)
File "", line 1, in 
File "", line 45, in 
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 149, in runAndLoadResults
return Processing.runAlgorithm(alg, parameters=parameters, onFinish=handleAlgorithmResults, feedback=feedback,
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 170, in runAlgorithm
raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm
Could not load source layer for INPUT: C:/Users/CMCA/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_fxLGYW/9e9a3cc555cb40ef89889a040fd7f3fd/OUTPUT.xtf not found

I also tried to do it manually, but the error still persist.
[image]
what is wrong with the file? or my qgis?

Comment: If you want people to analyse what is wrong with your file, you should make that file available somewhere!

Comment: your traceback is unreadable - you've lost all the line breaks

Comment: One error that is common in both approaches has to do with this file -- "C:/Users/CMCA/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_fxLGYW/9e9a3cc555cb40ef89889a040fd7f3fd/OUTPUT.xtf " - in the manual approach it says "...were not correctly generated", and in the script, the approach is saying "not found". I'd start with the file.

Comment: thank you for your answers